# display:flex is not supporting in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, flexbox

I have a display issue in [IE8 browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrxdg.png), as it's displaying my block's in a whole line. It is supposed to float, as it does it in [Chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEsIt.png). What needs to be fixed in order to work in IE8.

Here is my code: `      
        
        
         IE

```
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>

     `
```

and css part is `

```
     *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }

    body {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .grid {
      width: 1024px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
          -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
              flex-flow: row wrap;
      padding: 32px;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .grid:after {
      content: "";
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -webkit-flex: auto;
          -ms-flex: auto;
              flex: auto;
      margin-left: -1%;
    }
    .grid .item {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -webkit-flex: 1 0 24.25%;
          -ms-flex: 1 0 24.25%;
              flex: 1 0 24.25%;
      max-width: 24.25%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #bbb;
    }
    .grid .item:nth-child(4n+2), .grid .item:nth-child(4n+3), .grid 
     .item:nth-child(4n+4) {
      margin-left: 1%;
    }
    .grid .item:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4), .grid .item:nth-

     child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ .item {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    `
```

Comment: Flex was first introduced several **years** after IE8 was released. Of course it doesn't support it.

Comment: you can user float left

Comment: I have tried using float:left; but there is no change with IE.

Comment: with display inline

Comment: I even tried with *zoom: 1; *display: inline;. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I happens becuase, **ie-8** does not support flex property, but no problem we have a fix for that.

First of all use **ie specific stylesheet** as,

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to file/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

then include followsing css in that **ie.css** file,

```
.grid {
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.grid .item {
  float:left;
  width: 24.25%;
 }  

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both; 
}
```

Make sure to add a div with class '.**clearfix**' after the last '**item**', like

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

And it will work for **ie** also.

**Your complete HTML page will be like this,**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
*, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }

    body {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .grid {
      width: 1024px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
          -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
              flex-flow: row wrap;
      padding: 32px;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .grid:after {
      content: "";
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -webkit-flex: auto;
          -ms-flex: auto;
              flex: auto;
      margin-left: -1%;
    }
    .grid .item {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -webkit-flex: 1 0 24.25%;
          -ms-flex: 1 0 24.25%;
              flex: 1 0 24.25%;
      max-width: 24.25%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #bbb;
    }
    .grid .item:nth-child(4n+2), .grid .item:nth-child(4n+3), .grid 
     .item:nth-child(4n+4) {
      margin-left: 1%;
    }
    .grid .item:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4), .grid .item:nth-

     child(4n+1):nth-last-child(-n+4) ~ .item {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
</style>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>



<body>

<div class="grid">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Item</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried adding the ie.css just above my style.css. I also added the clearfix after the last item, still my IE seems to be having trouble with it. I have made the changes along with my previous changes including float:left and *display:inline.

Comment: add ie.css below style.css using ie-specific styles which I have mentioned. It is not necessary but keep style.css and ie.css path same, so there will be no confusion at all.

Comment: Yes, I have interchanged the order of style sheets. Still, what I see in IE is, they don't have margins between the items, but if I am manually setting the margin in .grid .item{}, under ie.css, it's affecting the layout in Chrome. Where do I need to change exactly to make things neat?

Comment: Even if you change style in ie.css it will not affect chrome, because you are using ie specific style, which will be used only on ie9 and less

Comment: @Narayanan can you show me your site live? So that, I can view it and tell you changes to be made if any.

Comment: I wanted to share my screenshot/site with you, but I don't know how to share it here.

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshot, please host your website somewhere so that I can view it live. There are so many free hsoting providers available over the internet, get used of that.